# AngularJS - Can't get AJAX request to work

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I'm new to `Angular` (few hours new). I'm getting pretty much what I want, by adjusting the demo. But i can't get my `AJAX` request to work.

I tried various solutions, but on gets in an endless loop (figured out that's the way how `Angular` works). In an other solution nothing really happens..

My current solution (tried to place the `peopleController` about everywhere):

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
    //$http is working in this

    var scrollItems = [];

    for (var i=1; i<=100; i++) {
        scrollItems.push('Item ' + i);
    }

    $scope.scrollItems = scrollItems;    


    function peopleController($scope,$http){
        // Simple GET request example :
        $http.get('/public/ajax.php').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("worked");
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            scope.people = data;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("fail");          
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
            });
     }          
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="peopleController">
     {{people}}
</div>
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/ng/areq?p0=peopleController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js:6:416
    at Mb (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js:19:510)
    at nb (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js:20:78)
    at $get (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js:74:494)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js:56:415
    at r (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js:7:408)
    at M (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js:56:281)
    at g (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js:51:201)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js:50:309
```

Hope someone can help me out here :)

[Other solutions i tried for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572629/angularjs-calls-http-constantly)

Comment: are you sure that you can define a controller inside another? try bringing the `peopleController` outside of the `mainController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a separate controller called peopleController you need to define it separately as follows:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
      //$http is working in this

      var scrollItems = [];

      for (var i=1; i<=100; i++) {
        scrollItems.push('Item ' + i);
      }

      $scope.scrollItems = scrollItems;    



 }]);

 app.controller('peopleController', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http){
        // Simple GET request example :
        $http.get('/public/ajax.php').
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log("worked");
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            $scope.people = data;
          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log("fail");        
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
          });
        } 
 }]);
```

Comment: This one says in console.log it "worked", but the data doesn't appear on screen + i still get an error:

ReferenceError: scope is not defined

Comment: Thnx! it works! (just the penultimate has to be removed), your my hero for today ;) !

Answer (score 1):

match the controller name in your html and js file, if it's 'peopleController' in you html file name it 'peopleController' in the controller rather than 'MainController'.

than change the line

```
function peopleController($scope,$http){
```

to

```
function peopleController(){
```

you use dependency injection in the controller function, not on the contained functions, the contained function already have access to $something because they are under the controller function's scope

Answer (score 1):

Your `view` must refer to the controller you declared, which is `MainController`:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
        {{people}}
</div>
```

Inside your `controller`, set `people` to `[]` and bound to `$scope`, remove the parameters you passed in `peopleController` and initiate the request. Caution: in the success handler, rename `scope` to `$scope`.

```
$scope.people = [];

peopleController(); //initiate your ajax request

function peopleController(){ //remove the parameters
        // Simple GET request example :
        $http.get('/public/ajax.php').
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log("worked");
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            $scope.people = data; //scope -> $scope
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("fail");        
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });
    }
```

`peopleController()` is misleading; its purpose is to get data. I'd recommend to rename it to `getPeople()`.

Comment: Your solution (and other comments) make sense! I tried it, but it gives me an error (ReferenceError: scope is not defined) and the app stops loading (more or less an empty screen).

Comment: Which line? See the details

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove $scope and $http from `peopleController` function which are overriding the existence of $http &amp;amp; $scope

Other thing you should mention `ng-controller='MainController'` instead of `ng-controller='peopleController'`

Also change the name `peopleController` to `getPeople`. I'm assuming that you want function there instead of controller.

Comment: thnx, makes sense, so I changed it. But I still get the error unfortunately.